# Homotopy Extension Property of mapping cone

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to show that for a topological space $X$ and subspace $A$,  the pair (mapping cone of the inclusion map, Cone $(A)$ ) has homotopy extension property, if the pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property.

But things are getting clumsy, so any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The homotopy extension property amounts to lifting for any $Z$
in the following diagram ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_extension_property#Visualisation)):

[image: Homotopy extension property]

So you need to show the lifting (dashed) in

[image]

Here the map $X \to Z^I$ exists by assumption. But by the definition of the mapping cone, the dashed arrow always exists for any $W$ in

[image]

For $W = Z^I$ you get the desired arrow in the second diagram.